# What should the contents of emma_ant.properties be?

Tags: eclipse, ant, properties, emma

I've been following this tutorial on [3. Getting Started (ANT)](http://emma.sourceforge.net/userguide/ar01s03.html), and it says `<taskdef resource="emma_ant.properties" classpathref="emma.lib" />` but does not give any reference to the contents of `emma_ant.properties`. Any ideas?

Other websites such as [3.4. How do I change an EMMA property default setting?](http://emma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) also leave things to be desired (and is based on the command prompt and not a digital file). I've found another website [Using EMMA with ANT for JUnit test coverage reporting](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/UsingEMMAWithANTForJUnitTestCoverageReporting), but again it leaves the properties file to the imagination (doesn't even provide an example file).

Any ideas on how to manipulate the emma_ant.properties to Load  and  custom tasks for ANT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but does not give any reference to the contents of emma_ant.properties. Any ideas?

Check for `emma.jar` & `emma_ant.jar` which you have placed in the path specified you will find `emma_ant.properties`

> Any ideas on how to manipulate the emma_ant.properties to Load and custom tasks for ANT?

You need not to manipulate the properties file to use the tasks.

To use emma tasks you should

```
<!-- directory that contains emma.jar and emma_ant.jar -->
<property name="emma.dir" value="${YOUR_BASE_DIR}/lib/emma" />

<!-- Set emma.lib to refer to the list of EMMA jar files -->
<path id="emma.lib">
    <fileset dir="${emma.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

and

```
<!-- Load <emma> custom tasks so that they can be used in ANT -->
<taskdef resource="emma_ant.properties" classpathref="emma.lib" />
```

and you should be able to use emma tasks.

Here are the contents of `emma_ant.properties` inside `emma.jar`

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------

emma:       com.vladium.emma.emmaTask
emmajava:   com.vladium.emma.emmajavaTask

# -------------------------------------------------------------
# end of file
```

Also Check out [Emma Property Summary](http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference/ch03s02.html) if it helps you...

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm meant to manipulate the `emma_ant.properties` to Load <emma> and <emmajava> custom tasks, leaves a lot to the imagination. Are you able to provide abetter explanation? (instead of just sending me to a site, I've already been too?)

Comment: Did you put in `emma.jar` file in the path specified as `emma.lib`?

Comment: Thanks SiB, for updating your question :) makes a lot more sense now! :)

Comment: Hey SiB, I was wondering could you look into my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171438/emma-instrumentation-classes-junit-testing-failing)