# EMMA with Junit, should I be testing with the instrumented classes or java classes?

Tags: java, ant, junit, emma

I've been going through this [tutorial](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/UsingEMMAWithANTForJUnitTestCoverageReporting) for my ANT Script for emma/junit, it states

> In the `<classpath>` element of `<junit>`, change the locations of your real classes, so that you are pointing at the ${instr.dir} attribute instead of your normal target/classes folder.

Here is my emma section from  of my build.xml for Apache Ant ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AzsuRHa1) link to full build.xml)

```
<!-- =================================================================== -->
<!-- Run the tests with EMMA
* depends from  compile                                                                                                                        -->
<!-- =================================================================== -->
<target name="emmatest" depends="compile" description="Tests the project with Emma Query" >
    <!-- ======================================================================= -->
    <!-- EMMA INSTRUMENTATION -->
    <!-- ======================================================================= -->
    <emma enabled="${emma.enabled}" >
        <instr instrpathref="emma.coverage.classes"
             destdir="${instr.dir}"
             metadatafile="${coverage.dir}/metadata.emma"
             merge="true"
             >
            <filter value="${emma.filter}" />
        </instr>
    </emma> 
    <junit fork="true" forkmode="once" >
         <test name="test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.AppenderLayoutTest" todir="${coverage.dir}">
          <formatter type="xml"/>
          </test>
         <classpath>
                <path refid="emma.lib" />
                <pathelement location="${instr.dir}"/>
                <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                   <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
        </classpath>
         <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.file=${coverage.dir}/coverage.emma" />
         <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.merge=false" />
    </junit>
</target>
```

The Build Section Results for `emma`: **JUNIT Fail Result, pointing to `${instr.dir}`**

```
 emmatest:
 [instr] processing instrumentation path ...
 [instr] instrumentation path processed in 109 ms
 [instr] [6 class(es) instrumented, 0 resource(s) copied]
 [instr] metadata merged into [C:\Users\Michael\workspace\log4jassignment.s06005586\build\emma-reports\metadata.emma] {in 42 ms}
 [junit] Test test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.AppenderLayoutTest FAILED
```

The Build Section results for `junitreport`: **JUNIT Pass Result, pointing to `real classes ${build.classes}`**

```
test:
[junit] Running test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.AppenderLayoutTest
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.504 sec
[junit] Running test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.StressTest
[junit] Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.526 sec
```

I was wondering why is my JUNIT Test `AppenderLayoutTest` failing with emma but passing with junit. I'm also pretty confident my `coverage file` isn't being created because the JUNIT for `AppenderLayoutTest` is  failing.

Am I testing with the wrong set of classes? or what I missed?

**Update: 8/28/2012 6:21 PM**

I then changed the

```
<test 
name="test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.AppenderLayoutTest"
todir="${coverage.dir}">
```

with

```
<batchtest>
    <fileset dir="${instr.dir}" includes="**/*Test.class" />
</batchtest>
```

And the updated Build Section Results for `emma`: **JUNIT Fail Result, pointing to `${instr.dir}`** where..

```
emmatest:
[instr] processing instrumentation path ...
[instr] instrumentation path processed in 105 ms
[instr] [6 class(es) instrumented, 0 resource(s) copied]
[instr] metadata merged into [C:\Users\Michael\workspace\log4jassignment.s06005586\build\emma-reports\metadata.emma] {in 89 ms}
[junit] TEST test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.AppenderLayoutTest FAILED
[junit] TEST test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.StressTest FAILED
[junit] Tests FAILED
```

**Update: 7:02 PM**

I added `<formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />`, And this is the output

```
emmatest:
[instr] [EMMA v2.1, build 5320 (stable) (2005/06/20 22:08:27)]
[instr] instrumentation path:
[instr] {
[instr]   C:\Users\Michael\workspace\log4jassignment.s06005586\build\classes
[instr] }
[instr] instrumentation output mode: copy
[instr] metadata output file: C:\Users\Michael\workspace\log4jassignment.s06005586\build\emma-reports\metadata.emma
[instr] metadata output merge mode: true
[instr] processing dir path entry [C:\Users\Michael\workspace\log4jassignment.s06005586\build\classes] ...
[instr] instrumentation path processed in 147 ms
[instr] [6 class(es) instrumented, 0 resource(s) copied]
[instr] metadata contains 6 entries
[instr] metadata merged into [C:\Users\Michael\workspace\log4jassignment.s06005586\build\emma-reports\metadata.emma] {in 49 ms}
[junit] Running test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.AppenderLayoutTest
[junit] Testsuite: test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.AppenderLayoutTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit]     Caused an ERROR
[junit] Illegal local variable table length 17 in method test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.AppenderLayoutTest.<init>()V
[junit] java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal local variable table length 17 in method test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.AppenderLayoutTest.<init>()V
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
[junit] TEST test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.AppenderLayoutTest FAILED
[junit] Running test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.StressTest
[junit] Testsuite: test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.StressTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit]     Caused an ERROR
[junit] Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 11 in method test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.StressTest.<init>()V at offset 4
[junit] java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 11 in method test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.StressTest.<init>()V at offset 4
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
[junit] TEST test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.StressTest FAILED
[junit] Tests FAILED
```

what is  `[junit] java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal local variable table length 17 in method test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.AppenderLayoutTest.<init>()V`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try replacing

```
<test 
name="test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.AppenderLayoutTest"
todir="${coverage.dir}">
```

with

```
<batchtest>
    <fileset dir="${instr.dir}" includes="**/*Test.class" />
</batchtest>
```

Lastly I would ask you to put some `sysout` in your test and see what is going wrong in the test. This might something to do with configuration I feel.

Comment: Thanks I just tried, I updated my question. But the tests are still failing, I feel I'm a little closer to the solution now though. Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated ! Regards

Comment: Lastly I would ask you to put some sysout in your test and see what is going wrong in the test. This might something to do with configuration I feel.

Comment: I haven't used `ant` much, and I read from this [website](http://www.mentby.com/Group/apache-ant/timeout-in-junit-and-sysout.html) to add the attribute `showoutput="true"` to my `<junit>` task but no `sysout` is being printed. I'm using the default configuration from `emma.jar` and `emma_ant.jar`.

Comment: This means your test Class is not being executed... Check the path `${instr.dir}` are the instrumented classes present?

Comment: you have two folders inside `emma-instr` can you try deleting everything and test again.

Comment: I did and the same thing happens it creates the package path to the classes in the folder `emma-instr` (I copy/pasted the code from `Add EMMA instrumentation to your test target` on [UsingEMMAWithANTForJUnitTestCoverageReporting](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/UsingEMMAWithANTForJUnitTestCoverageReporting))

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15935/discussion-between-sib-and-killrawr)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the latest trace you shared it seems can use

```
-XX:-UseSplitVerifier
```

as VM argument to get rid of the error related to JDK7.

or [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010665/testng-emma-cobertura-coverage-and-jdk-7-result-in-classformaterror-and-verif)