# Java 7 with emma and junit causing java.lang.VerifyError and Illegal local variable Errors

Tags: eclipse, ant, java-7, emma

So I'm getting these errors

> [junit] Illegal local variable table length 17 in method test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.AppenderLayoutTest.()V
>
> [junit] java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 11 in method test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.StressTest.()V at offset 4
>
> [junit] java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal local variable table length 17 in method test.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.AppenderLayoutTest.()V

And I would like to know how I can fix it...

**What I've Read:**

- [Java 7 JVM VerifyError in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970622/java-7-jvm-verifyerror-in-eclipse)
- [Testng, Emma, Cobertura, coverage and JDK 7 result in ClassFormatError and VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010665/testng-emma-cobertura-coverage-and-jdk-7-result-in-classformaterror-and-verif)
- [EMMA code coverage](https://sourceforge.net/p/emma/discussion/373867/thread/963f0d6f/)
- [Using EMMA with ANT for JUnit test coverage reporting](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/UsingEMMAWithANTForJUnitTestCoverageReporting)
- [Bug 141252 - 1.6 compiler ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "" in class file (FIXED)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=141252)
- [3.2. : instrumenting Java classes on-the-fly](http://emma.sourceforge.net/userguide_single/userguide.html#N101C4)

**What I've Done:**

Resources:

- [build.xml](http://pastebin.com/arxhiFey) (will expire in 24 hours)
- [build.xml output](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3ZfAFXpN) (will expire in 24 hours)
- [Ant diagnostics report](http://pastebin.com/ytj6sa9f) (will expire in 24 hours)
- [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171438/emma-with-junit-should-i-be-testing-with-the-instrumented-classes-or-java-class/12171942#comment16292650_12171942)
- [maven-emma-plugin-0.6.jar](http://hivelocity.dl.sourceforge.net/project/emma/plugins-testing/maven-1.0-plugin-0.6/maven-emma-plugin-0.6.jar)
- [emma.jar and emma_ant.jar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/emma/files/emma-release/2.0.5312/emma-2.0.5312.zip/download)

For some really crazy reason the JUnit Passes on `target="test"` but fails on `target="emmatest"`.

This is the output on command prompt from `java -version`

```
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

I've tried setting the default arguments for my `java7 JRE` to `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` from [here](https://vikashazrati.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/quicktip-verifyerror-with-jdk-7/)

[image: arguments]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/dvsh1eoc.n0m.png))</sub>

I've also tried to make it complaint with `JDK 1.6` on the `Project Properties`.

[image: complaint]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/4jxuj4eb.rae.png))</sub>

JUnit direct testing results (no errors on the trace)

[image: junit]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/wicrvpsi.5gw.png))</sub>

I'm out of options, please help! :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds strange.

First, check your code to see if you have used new grammar features introduced in JDK 1.7, like `try-with-resource` or `diamond operator`.

I met this VerifyError before, when using cobertura. However, when I set `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` to the `junit` task, it is resolved. I set it by specifying a `<jvmarg>`
nested element to `junit` task.

Also, most of the coverage libs seem to support JDK1.7 very poorly. However, **Jacoco** works fine with JDK1.7 so I am using it for now.

Comment: Thanks I managed to fix it, by just downloading the [JDK6u25](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u25-download-346242.html) and changing the library path in my project/eclipse.

Comment: @Killrawr Happy to see that! Yes, downgrade the JDK version is also a choice.

Comment: @Killrawr finally you managed to get rid of it by downgrading to java6 as I advised :).

Comment: @SiB Could you take a look at [basic.xml is not in either pmd-bin-5.0-alpha or pmd-bin-5.0.0 directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193950/basic-xml-is-not-in-either-pmd-bin-5-0-alpha-or-pmd-bin-5-0-0-directories)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer: *Cobertura* seems to be the root in my case, too.

Answer (score 1):

`-XX:-UseSplitVerifier`

Does work for me and I did not have to downgrade **JRE** from **1.7** to **1.6**