# No ruleset or basic.xml in the sourceforge pmd-bin-5.0.0 download

Tags: ant, pmd, sourceforge

I've been reading all over the [PMD Website](https://web.archive.org/web/20121030003705/http://pmd.sourceforge.net:80/howtomakearuleset.html) and it has all these [references](https://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/plugins/pmd/faq.html) to   `<rule ref="rulesets/basic.xml/UnnecessaryConversionTemporary"/>` but I cant find the file `basic.xml` in either the `pmd-bin-5.0.0` or  `pmd-bin-5.0-alpha` directory downloaded from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd/5.0.0/).

As you can see in the screen dump I've provided below, I've done a search for this `basic.xml` and came up empty handed.

[image: Basic XML]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/m2nxe032.pto.png))</sub>

In the next screen shot of `pmd-bin-5.0.0` there is no folder called **ruleset**

[image: pmd directory]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/tsvpb3lo.uap.png))</sub>

Pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/DGuHzxg3) to ruleset.xml  *(Expires in 24 hours)*

```
<property name="pmd.dir" value="${basedir}/pmd" /><!-- directory that contains pmd.jar -->
<property name="pmd.test.results" location="${build.dir}/pmd"/>
<path id="pmd.lib" >
    <fileset dir="${pmd.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
<target name="pmd" depends="compile" >
     <taskdef name="pmd" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask" classpathref="pmd.lib"/>
     <pmd shortFilenames="true">
           <ruleset>basic,imports</ruleset>
           <formatter type="text" toFile="pmd-ant-results.txt"/>
           <fileset dir="src">
                 <include name="**/*.java"/>
           </fileset>
     </pmd>
</target>
```

When my ant script is executed it comes back with this error

```
  [pmd] net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetNotFoundException: Can't find resource rulesets/basic.xml.  Make sure the resource is a valid file or URL or is on the CLASSPATH.
  BUILD FAILED
  C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\log4jassignment.s06005586\build.xml:131:      java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find the class Can't find resource rulesets/basic.xml.  Make sure the resource is a valid file or URL or is on the CLASSPATH.
```

Project Explorer

[image: project]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/4sx5juq0.nm0.png))</sub>

So that tells me that the `basic.xml` file doesn't come from the `pmd-5.0.0.jar` file but in fact comes from somewhere else, Thus my question is what is the contents of pmd's `basic.xml`, and other required xml files (how am I meant to get my hands on them)? or do these files not exist and am I meant to recreate them myself (and if I am, how would I go about doing this?)?

Comment: is there a folder called ruleset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded `pmd-bin-5.0-alpha.zip` from [PMD Website](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/howtomakearuleset.html).

Once you unzip `pmd-bin-5.0-alpha.zip` file; 
go inside the `lib` directory and 
try to extract the content of `pmd-5.0-alpha.jar`.

I was able to find the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhkCu.png):

[image: basic.xml]

Comment: Now I'm getting this error `C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\log4jassignment.s06005586\build.xml:112: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.xpath.Initializer`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194980/could-not-initialize-class-net-sourceforge-pmd-lang-xpath-initializer